# Saving A List For a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview, gson

Here is the declaration of the list:

```
public List<gameRowItem> GameRowItem;
```

Here is the setOnItemClickListener code:

```
gameListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position == plusPosition) //when plusSign is clicked
            {

                someGame = new Game();  //instance of game class
                someGame.gameName = preferences.getString("Game Name", null);
                gson = new Gson();

                jsonOfSomeGame = gson.toJson(someGame);       // put someGame into json
                editor.putString("someGame", jsonOfSomeGame);  //put some game into sharedPreferences
                editor.commit();

                jsonOfSomeGame = preferences.getString("someGame", null);  //receive json of some game
                savedSomeGame = gson.fromJson(jsonOfSomeGame, Game.class);  // turn json into object of game
                arrayOfGames.add(0, savedSomeGame);

                jsonOfNewGame = gson.toJson(newGame);
                editor.putString("newGame", jsonOfNewGame);
                editor.commit();

                jsonOfNewGame = preferences.getString("newGame", null);
                savedNewGame = gson.fromJson(jsonOfNewGame, gameRowItem.class);
                savedNewGame = new gameRowItem(savedSomeGame.gameName);

                jsonOfGameRowItem = gson.toJson(GameRowItem);
                editor.putString("GameRowItem", jsonOfGameRowItem);
                editor.commit();

                jsonOfGameRowItem = preferences.getString("GameRowItem", null);
                gameRowItem[] savedGameRowItem = gson.fromJson(jsonOfGameRowItem, gameRowItem[].class);



                GameRowItem.add(0, savedNewGame);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                plusPosition++;


            }else{
                Intent toGamePlay = new Intent(ListOfGames.this, GamePlay.class);
                startActivity(toGamePlay);
            }


        }
    });
```

I am trying to save the items on the ListView so that even when I leave the Activity it will still be there.  As you might be able to see, I have been trying to use Gson to store objects in hope that it will save the item on the ListView.  However, I now realize that I should be trying to save the actual List that is GameRowItem, I'm just not sure how to go about saved GameRowItem.  I even attempted to save GameRowItem toward the bottom of the code, but was unsuccessful. Any help would be appreciated, and if you need any more code feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do? It's not very clear.

Also, you should start class names with a capital letter and variables with a lowercase letter. Variable names for collections like your List should be plural. This will make your code easier to understand for others.


    public List<GameRowItem> gameRowItems;

Comment: I am trying to save GameRowItem to SharedPreferences so that when I add an item to GameRowItem it will permanently be there on the ListView even if I switch between Activities. Thanks for the suggestion, I do need to improve on my naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate classes for the UI and the data (model and list).

You already have your model: `Game`. Create `GamesList` with methods to load a list of `Game` from storage, save a list, add a new `Game`, etc.

Then in your activity, load the `GamesList` and populate the ListView. When you click on the plus, add a new `GameRowItem` to `GamesList` and save it.

I prefer saving list to a private file instead of `SharedPreferences` since it's easy to store objects that implement `Serializable`.

```
public class Game implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    // ...
}


public class GamesList {
    private static final String FILENAME = "games.ser";

    private List<Game> list;

    public GamesList() {
        list = new ArrayList<Game>();
    }

    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public GamesList add(Game item) {
        // Add at the front of the list
        list.add(0, item);

        return this;
    }

    public Game get(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        list.remove(position);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void loadFromCache(Context context) {
        try {
            InputStream in = context.openFileInput(FILENAME);

            ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            list = (List<Game>) objIn.readObject();
            objIn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public void saveToCache(Context context) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            out.writeObject(list);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGamesList = new GamesList();
    mGamesList.loadFromCache(this);
}

gameListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(position == plusPosition) //when plusSign is clicked
        {

            someGame = new Game();  //instance of game class
            // fill game per your logic
            mGamesList.add(someGame).saveToCache(ListOfGames.this);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            plusPosition++;


        }else{
            Intent toGamePlay = new Intent(ListOfGames.this, GamePlay.class);
            startActivity(toGamePlay);
        }


    }
});
```